# Error while bootstraping ec2 instance through a bash script

Tags: amazon-ec2, chef-infra

I'm trying to bootstrap an ec2 instance through a bash script. Following is the command i use,

```
knife bootstrap xx.xx.xx.xx --sudo --ssh-user ubuntu --identity-file ~/Desktop/temp/temp.pem --node-name test
```

The above command works when it's executed directly from the terminal. But when it is included in a bash script it doesn't execute properly. ( In the bash script I use "cd ~/chef-repo/" to change the directory to chef-repo, there's no issue finding the "knife" command)

The error I get is,

```
Connecting to xx.xx.xx.xx
ERROR: Network Error: Connection refused - connect(2)
Check your knife configuration and network settings
```

Anybody knows why am I getting this error ?

Comment: Does the directory in which the bash script execute contain a ".chef" directory? In a script I would advise using the "-c" parameter so that you always know which configuration file is being used.

Comment: This is a networking error - can you access the ec2 instance at xx.xx.xx.xx via telnet or ping?

Comment: @Mark : I tried Linux "cd" command to change to chef-repo directory and executed the script within the chef-repo directory as well but no difference in the output.

Comment: @sethvargo: I didn't try to ping to the instance since it can be bootstrapped using direct terminal ( wintout bash script)